# How to customize the frame background color and borderline width

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I wish to customize the background color and the weight and color of the border using `titlesec` (not using `mdframed`).

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno,fleqn,xcolor=x11names]{book} %
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts} %
\usepackage{titlesec} %
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc} % more advanced but essential here
\usepackage[english]{babel} %

\titleformat{\section}[frame] %
{\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12.8}{14}\selectfont}
        {}{8pt}
{\;\;\thesection\hskip 0.7em}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is Chapter No 1}

\section{A titletec section in a frame - too tall and not shaded}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you see [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226742/how-does-one-change-the-frame-size-and-colors-in-the-frame-option-of-titlesec-as) to a previous question of yours? It only uses the `framed` package, which `titlesec uses for its framed style.

Comment: The other question of yours already has two answers. Instead of opening a new duplicate question, you can ask for clarifications/modifications to the answers using comments to the answers in the original question.

Comment: Question now answered very satisfactorily.

Comment: Not clear what is left to do.